# jquery mobile issues

Tags: jquery, mobile

On my PHP site I use jquery to do little things here and there, but one page in particular uses it  heavily.

I get people telling me that "it doesn't work on mobile phones", could this be a case of a code or script issue, or is it just that certain phones don't like jquery scripts?

My site has a sidebar thats refreshed every 10 secs using jquery, no one's ever said that didn't work, its only since I've added this certain page. Im guessing it's a code issue.

Basically Im asking if there's anything I can do about it.

Comment: It might depend on browser. If the phone's browser does not support javascript (E.g. Opera Mini) then the jquerymobile page will not work.

Comment: updated my post a little. I have other parts of my site that have always used jquery its only recently with a new page they've started saying "no worky!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently been building a mobile hybrid app that relies heavily on jquery. Jquery works fine on mobile phones in a broad sense, but there are some specific issues.

Animation:

Animation can be slow and jumpy, but as i discovered last night, you can force GPU hardware acceleration to work with jquery as well as CSS transitions, and the performance improvement is substantial. I accomplished this by using the css style below on all divs and images to force the hardware into thinking it in rendering 3d graphics:

```
div, img {-webkit-transform:translateZ(0); }
```

Effect Delay:

When a jquery event is called, such as a button "click", it can take maybe 1 second for the event to happen, depending on what the event is and what is being called into play.

I don't even use jquery mobile, just normal jquery, and besides very minor performance issues that only real nitpickers will complain about, jquery can run perfectly fine. It's just a case of optimizing your code and developing certain coding habits to reduce the load on the processing engine.

Comment: thanks, so its a code specific issue thats causing problems with mine.

Comment: more than likely. optimize everything and force hardware acceleration and you should see significant improvement